# Cómo ejecutar una función javascript que llama a una función php

Tags: php, ajax, funciones

Tengo una función javascript que se ejecuta con un evento 'onclick' y que quiero que llame a una función php para cerrar sesión. He visto que para conectar javascript con php lo mejor es utilizar ajax.

Por tanto hice lo siguiente:

```
function closeSessionOnClick(){
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '../../SERVER_MANAGEMENT/session_management.php',
            data: {functionName: 'delete_session'},
            success: function () {
            }
     }
});
```

Mi duda es, ¿qué debería ir dentro del success?. Se trata de una función php que únicamente ejecuta una acción, no devuelve un valor ni nada. (He puesto un switch porque habría más funciones, no solo esta)

```
switch($_POST['functionName']) {
      case 'delete_session':
      delete_session();
      break;
}
function delete_session(){
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
        session_destroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Con el success, en caso de que quieras, puedes verificar que todo a ido bien y que se a añaido. Para ello podrías sacar una alerta o lo que quieras sin tener que esperar respuesta. Ajax también tiene un fail por si ha habido algún error a la hora de realizar alguna operación.

Comment: El php debería devolver algún código, al menos un booleano true/false o 1/0 para verificar que se ejecutó según lo esperado.

Comment: cuando no devuelve nada es tipico en http devolver en el [status](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:C%C3%B3digos_de_estado_HTTP) 204

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo general para estos casos se suele requerir que el servidor devuelva un JSON como respuesta, porque es mucho más fácil tratarlo, así que en la petición Ajax agregaremos un `dataType: 'json'`, también debes poner cómo se llama el parámetro que esperas en el `success`:

```
function closeSessionOnClick(){
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '../../SERVER_MANAGEMENT/session_management.php',
            data: {functionName: 'delete_session'},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response.msg); 
            }
     }
});
```

En cuanto a PHP, hacen falta más controles y devolver la respuesta:

```
$mFunction= ( empty($_POST['functionName']) ) ? NULL; $_POST['functionName'];
if ( $mFunction ){
    switch( $mFunction ) {
      case 'delete_session':
          $msg=delete_session();
          break;
      //Completar....
    }
} else {
    $msg="No se posteó ninguna función";
}
$mResponse=array("msg"=>$msg);
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); 
echo json_encode($mResponse);
```

---

```
/*Función*/
function delete_session(){
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
        session_destroy();
        $msg= "Sesión name destroyed";
    } else {
        $msg= "No sesión name";
    }  
    return $msg;
}
```

La cuestión es armar un código que sea lógico. En algunos casos, tu JSON de respuesta podría tener por ejemplo una clave `error` en caso de error o `success`, o un boolenao o lo que fuera para actuar en consecuencia.

Answer (score 2):

Recordá que el javascript se ejecuta en el navegador, y el php en el servidor, y hacen esto sobre http(s) que es un protocolo "pregunta-respuesta".

Con esto quiero decir que el `php` debe devolver algo para decir que la sesión se cerró correctamente o no. Lo que devuelve puede ser simplemente un `string` o un `json`.

En `success`, deberías validar esa respuesta para determinar si la sesión se cerró en el servidor y mostrar alguna confimación o un mensaje como "muchas gracias, nos vemos!"